# postgresql code for delete operation in table type

Tags: database-migration, postgresql-9.5, user-defined-types

I have a code for deleting table type in MSSQL.Have to convert into PGSQL which is giving error.
Looking forward for a PGSQL code which deletes from a Table Type User defined:
below MSSQL CODE:

```
declare @Entity TRef_StructureTree readonly //input parameter from procedure
DELETE Tef_StructureTree 
FROM Tef_StructureTree
inner join (select * from @Entity) as source
on Tef_StructureTree.ChildCodeBDR=source.ChildCodeBDR AND 
Tef_StructureTree.ChildScheme=source.ChildScheme;
```

Below is definition of USer defined Table type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Tef_StructureTree] AS TABLE(
    [ChildCodeBDR] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ChildScheme] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    )
```

below PGSQL CODE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UpdateStrucTree(v_entity Tef_StructureTree[])
 as 
begin
    DELETE FROM v_entity   
        where v_entity."ChildCodeBDR" in(select "source"."ChildCodeBDR" from  unnest(v_entity)  as "source" )
        and v_entity."ChildScheme" in (select "source"."ChildScheme"  from  unnest(v_entity)  as "source" );
 end;
```

ERROR:  relation "v_entity" does not exist
Please Help by providing the equivalent!!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Sorry its 'v_entity'...I made a mistake while pasting the code in portal...Still the error persists

Comment: If you are doing a migration today, you should migrate to Postgres 12, not to a version that is going to be de-supported in 6 months.

Comment: Sorry our company does not have Postgresql 12

Comment: Then at least use 11 or 10. But it makes zero sense to migrate to a soon to be de-supported version. It's like migrating to SQL Server 2005 today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter is called `v_entitydata` not `v_entity`, so you either need to change your parameter name or the reference to it. You probably want to delete from the table `Tef_StructureTree` not from the passed array.

Your function's structure is also not valid for Postgres as the function body needs to be provided as a string, e.g. using [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).

You can simplify the condition, by only using a single sub-query as well.

So putting all that together, the function should look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UpdateStrucTree(v_entity "Tef_StructureTree"[])
as 
$$
  DELETE FROM "Tef_StructureTree"
  where ("ChildCodeBDR", "ChildScheme") in (select "ChildCodeBDR", "ChildScheme"
                                            from unnest(v_entity) )
$$
language sql;
```